# Check if a given DB object used in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, function, sql-view

Hi does any one know how to check if a given DB object (Table/View/SP/Function) is used inside Oracle.

For example to check if the table "A" is used in any SP/Function or View definitions. I am trying to cleanup unused objects in the database.

I tried the query select * from all_source WHERE TEXT like '%A%' (A is the table name). Do you thing it is safe to assume it is not being used if it does not return any results?

Comment: Interesting question. If an object isn't referenced by some other object, is it gauranteed to be useless? Do you know that no user will try to use that object in the future? Or do you *only* want to preserve objects that are referenced by some other object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [ASKTOM question](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4977262687416):

> You'll have to enable auditing and then come back in 3 months to see.
>
> We don't track this information by default -- also, even with auditing, it may be very 
>   possible to have an object that is INDIRECTLY accessed (eg: via a foreign key for 
>   example) that won't show up.
>
> You can try USER_DEPENDENCIES but that won't tell you about objects referenced by code in 
>   client apps or via dynamic sql

There's code in the thread for checking `ALL_SOURCE`, but it's highlighted that this isn't a silver bullet.